# Active thread count in cluster less than kafka topic partitions in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am using ConsumeKafka in Apache Nifi to consume data from a kafka topic with 15 partitions. ConsumeKafka processor has concurrency of 18 (6 nodes * 3 concurrent task/node )

[image: ConsumeKafka Processor]

Total threads running on cluster below : 10

[image: Total active threads = 10]

I was expecting total threads=15 as i have 15 partitions on my kafka topic. 
I see 15 unique consumer-IDs as well. How is nifi allocating threads in this case ?

[image: Kafka consumer-ID per partition]

Comment: have you adjusted the overall timer drive thread pool (from the controller settings in top right menu)? 10 is the default number of threads so that you would be the max

Comment: @BryanBende thanks, i increased the max thread pool count to 100. But i still see the count dynamically changing. It should have 15 threads active all the time for ConsumeKafka processor(as its attached to 15 partitions) ? each consumer-id is unique (unique thread/partition), can i map each consumer-id to unique count of thread in cluster ?